# How to modify np array by slicing through the broadcast of an index vector?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have this m x n numpy array which I want to apply certain operation over the row elements. Although, it must be cast only on those elements whose index is prior to those specified by the entries on a vector of indexes.

I've already gone through the classic for-loop way, but I was expecting something more NumPythonic.

The following code would complete the job:

```
for i,j in enumerate(x):
    M[i, 0:j] = 2*M[i, 0:j]
```

But I was look for a broadcast, no-for approach. Any Ideas?

For example, lets say that

```
M = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [ 6, 7, 8, 9,10]]

x = [2, 3]
```

and our application is to double certain element. According to the indexes specified in x we should have the resulting array:

```
M = [[ 2, 4, 3, 4, 5],
     [12,14,16, 9,10]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two related ways which turn out to be roughly equally fast:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

M = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [ 6, 7, 8, 9,10]]

x = [2, 3]

def f():
    MM = np.array(M)
    xx = np.array(x)
    MM[np.arange(5)<xx[:,None]] *= 2
    return MM

def g():
    MM = np.array(M)
    xx = np.array(x)
    MM *= 1 + (np.arange(5)<xx[:,None])
    return MM

print(f())
print(g())
M = 1000*M
x = 1000*x
print(timeit(f,number=1000))
print(timeit(g,number=1000))
```

Sample run:

```
[[ 2  4  3  4  5]
 [12 14 16  9 10]]
[[ 2  4  3  4  5]
 [12 14 16  9 10]]
1.1994759310036898
1.1547658089984907
```